# Mongodb object id and pagination

Tags: mongodb, pagination

I do not quite understand something with surrounding object id comparison and natural ordering, specifically -

Since each object id is greater than previous object id, with exception of ids generated within the same second, in which case there is no guarantee which is greater, does same range paginated query always guarantee that ordering on a page will not change, assuming no documents on that page were deleted?

It intuitively seems like answer should be 'yes', because each new id will be on a subsequent page, but natural ordering specifically does not guarantee order under all conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Besides document update and delete, there is a third kind of change that affects the natural order: **document's growth pattern**.

When a document outgrows its initial space allocation, it is moved, thus modifying the natural order. This scenario may even lead to a new side effect: when a new document is inserted, it can be stored in that "hole" left behind by the first document.

So, for a **Normal Collection**, you can't guarantee that the natural order will remaing the same. If you need to rely in the document insertion order, you should consider [Capped Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/).